# How to print an image in raw mode in C#?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, printing

I'm trying to print text and images directly to the printer, without passing by the windows drivers. I must print this way, because this application is intended for serial needle printers, and if I try printing using the Graphics method

```
/*Text Print*/
_printPageEventArgs.Graphics.DrawString(
    _printArray.ElementAt(i).Text,
    _printArray.ElementAt(i).Font,
    Brushes.Black,
    ClientRectangle,
    stringFormat);

/*Image Print*/
printPageEventArgs.Graphics.DrawImage(
   _printArray.ElementAt(i).Image,
    _printArray.ElementAt(i).StartPosX_100Inch,
    _printArray.ElementAt(i).FinalStartPosY_100Inch,
    _printArray.ElementAt(i).ImageWidth_100Inch,
    _printArray.ElementAt(i).ImageHeight_100Inch);
```

the printer takes forever to print anything.
So I'm using the printer's DLL to write it directly

```
public static extern UInt32 PrtWrite(IntPtr hPrt, byte[] pbWriteBuffer, 
    UInt32 nNumberOfBytesToWrite, ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

But I'm unable to convert the image to the correct byte format. Tried this conversions but none worked, all I get is garbled text:

```
//TEST 1
UInt32 dwNoOfBytesWritten = 0;
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\zzz.jpg");
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
byte[] imageToPrint = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
PrtWrite(_printerPointer, imageToPrint, (UInt32)imageToPrint.Length, 
    ref dwNoOfBytesWritten);

//TEST 2
UInt32 dwNoOfBytesWritten = 0;
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\zzz.jpg");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] imageToPrint = ms.ToArray();
PrtWrite(_printerPointer, imageToPrint, (UInt32)imageToPrint.Length, 
    ref dwNoOfBytesWritten);
```

This is an API for Wincor Nixdorf printers.

In their SDK, the method is defined as:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) DWORD PrtWrite (HANDLE hPRT, 
    LPBYTE pbWriteBuffer, DWORD dwLenWriteBuffer, LPDWORD pdwNoOfBytesWritten);
```

And this is all I've from their manual:

> The PrtWrite function writes nNumberOfBytesToWrite bytes of the
>   contents of pbWriteBuffer to the printer. The function can be used to
>   send data of any kind, normal print data as well as printer control
>   sequences.
>
> Please note that PrtWrite provides no character code mapping. So the
>   printout depends on the loaded character generator.
>
> hPrt -> Handle to the printer returned by PrtOpen.
>
> pbWriteBuffer -> Pointer to the buffer containing the data to be
>   written to the printer
>
> nNumberOfBytesToWrite -> Specifies the number of bytes to write to the
>   printer
>
> lpNumberOfBytesWritten -> Pointer to the variable that receives the
>   number of bytes written

Comment: *Much* better.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming the jpeg data right to the printer will most assuredly not work.  Many older printers worked by dumping ASCII down to the printer directly and turning that into characters.  I know that EPSON, for example, was still using their old protocol into the late '90s at least.  To get graphics, one sent down "escape sequences."  These are blocks of data that start with an escape character and include specifically formatted data.  This was de rigeur in the '80's and was pretty much the whole reason why people started writing print drivers in the first place: every manufacturer used different sequences and/or had different bugs in their protocols.

So you will need whatever documentation is available for the print protocol so you can implement it, and then you'll have to work around the bugs and quirks, of which there will be at least one, guaranteed.  If you can't find the documentation, maybe you can find an open source UNIX driver that you can pick apart.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question ("will most assuredly not work").  It's more a comment, or you need to prove specifically why the call to that specific DLL with the *correct* data (not as the poster has it now) cannot work.

Comment: casperOne: Serial needle printers are older than the jpeg format, it's unreasonable to expect direct support. plinth: +1

Comment: Tried with a BMP image file and got the same result

Answer (score 0):

The Wincor Nixdorf printer SDK / driver implements a CEN/XFS printer and needs to be instructed in the proper way. Dumping arbitrary binary data is unfortunately not going to give you an image in hard-copy. If you want to do something like that, please look into the GDI drivers. These do the translation between these worlds.

PrintRaw can be used to send sequences of bytes directly to the printer device. The string can either contain printer known escape sequences or Macros. I don't have a manual of escape sequences or macro's at hand, but please contact Wincor Nixdorf HQ or you supplier and ask them for the CSCW or CSCO documentation. This should contain the examples you're looking for.